# Every friday and saturday - List

Tags: python, list

The task is writing a function, which returns average hours of sleep in a week. Excluding fridays and saturdays. The input is a list of hours, starting at monday.

```
def averageSleep(hours):
    fridays = hours[4::-5]
    saturdays = hours[5::-6]
    length = len(hours)
    final = (sum(hours)-sum(fridays)-sum(saturdays)) / (length - 2)
    return final
        



print(averageSleep([6, 7.5, 3.5, 6, 9, 10, 7, 6, 7, 4]))
```

The function that I wrote returns:

```
5.875
```

Which is correct. Excluding items 9 and 10 (friday and saturday) from the list. The problem is, however, that passing in more list items (yielding more fridays and saturdays) makes the function return wrong results.  `hours[4::-5]` and `hours[5::-6]` just don't work for more fridays and saturdays.

Any idea how to pick all the fridays and saturdays from the list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look up how [list slicing works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation). `hours[x:y:z]` gives you elements of `hours` starting at the `x`th index, up to (but not including) the `y`th index, with a step of `z` elements. To get fridays, you want to skip 7 elements, starting at the `4`th index, so you need to do

```
fridays = hours[4::7]
saturdays = hours[5::7]
```

Also note that you'll have to divide the sum by `(len(hours) - len(fridays) - len(saturdays))` to get the correct mean.

Comment: Thank you very much, sir! :)